# Prevent socat from orphaning EXEC: processes?

Tags: expect, socat, orphan-process

I'm creating a quick `socat` TCP listener and then running a simple `expect` script.

Let's start the listener:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:5000,fork EXEC:my_exp_script
```

Which then listens on port 5000, accepts, forks, and executes `my_exp_script` here:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
expect {
         "hello" { send "world" ; exp_continue }
}
```

Simple enough BUT *every* `my_exp_script` forked process orphans when the connection dies (and requires a `kill -9`).  **How do I ensure non-ophaning of `socat`'s spawned processes?**

Comment: Just a guess: after the "hello" line, add `eof {exit}`